# Refer Names of a Button created from for loops Iteration variables and use it in python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am facing a very basic issue here . I want to create 100s of Buttons and to make them I want to use loops preferably for loop and create Button Names in the loop itself so i can use it later in the program logic i.e. example for i=1 i want to create Button1 and for i=100 i want button Button100 , however i am not sure how to do that in Python Kivy .

This is same thing which we can do in Linux using &variable name and sometime eval .Please see the code below for better . Comments will describe the issue here :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.clock import Clock



class RootWidget(GridLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.parent = GridLayout(cols=6)
        for i in (1,2,3,4,5,6):
            for j in (1,2,3,4,5,6):
                #Want to make self.BName s value as ButtonName%s%s
                self.BName= 'ButtonName%s%s'%(i,j)
                print "Button Name should be ",self.BName
                self.BName = Button(text='%s%s'%(i,j))
                self.parent.add_widget(self.BName)

        Clock.schedule_once(lambda a:self.update(),1)

        return self.parent

    def update(self):
        print "I am update function"
        for child in self.parent.children:
            print child

        #Want to make use ButtonName11 and not BName
        self.BName.text = "hello"
        #self.ButtonName11.text= "hello"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using this concept?

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.__dict__['Button{}'.format(i)] = Button(text='Button no. {}'.format(i))

>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.Button5.text
Button no. 5
>>> foo.Button98.text
Button no. 98
```

Comment: This one dosent seem to work .. If you wish try creating same in the code i pasted in my question

Comment: It's the concept, not the actual code required. You were essentially asking how to dynamically add attributes to an object, right?

Comment: not able to achieve what i want from the concept you provided

Comment: @paarthbatra My understanding of how to add a button is that you assign an instance of `Button()` to a variable, and then you use this variable when calling the `add_widget()` function. Is your question how to create a variable with a name that is generated from your for loops?

Comment: @paarthbatra That is exactly what my concept does. You may want to reread my answer again, as I changed line 4 to assign a Button instance instead of a string

Answer (score 0):

Scorpion_God way of doing it should work, however, a clearer way is using [setattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

Here's some example code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def create_buttons(self):
        for i in range(10):
            setattr(self, 'my_name{}'.format(i), i)

foo = Foo()
foo.my_name3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'my_name3'
foo.create_buttons()
foo.my_name3
3
```